# Rails 2 -> Rails 3 upgrade fails with complaints about associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, upgrade

I've been struggling with this issue for a while and I just can't get a handle on it.

I've got a site which runs fine on Rails 2.3.18/ruby1.8.7

I'm trying to get it to Rails3.  I've followed the guides and done the view updates (using rails_xss).  I'm now trying to get the test suite to pass and running into the following strange issue:

```
/Users/jon/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.20/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:71:
in `reflect_on_association': undefined method `[]'   
for #<ActiveRecord::Reflection::AssociationReflection:0x00000100b607a0> (NoMethodError)
from  /Users/jon/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord- 3.0.20/lib/active_record/autosave_association.rb:138:in `has_many'
from /projects/mau/app/models/studio.rb:7:in `<class:Studio>'
from /projects/mau/app/models/studio.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
...
from /Users/jon/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.20/lib/rails/application.rb:134:in `initialize!'
from /Users/jon/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.20/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
from /projects/mau/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
from /projects/mau/spec/spec_helper.rb:3:in `require'
from /projects/mau/spec/spec_helper.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
```

The seemingly relevant code bits would be that my `Studio` model has many `artists`.  And the `Artist` model is derived from `User`.

```
class Studio < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
  ...
end

class Artist < User
  ...
end 

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :studio
  ...
end
```

I've still got `restful_authentication` in the project and was planning to rip it out but hoping that i could do that after getting a test suite running.  At this point, I can't run `rails` anything because things fail as soon as I access one of these troubled objects.

I've looked into upgrading ruby (1.9.3) but still run into the same issue.

I've dug in deep with a debugger but can't find anything relevant.

I've tried specifying the `belongs_to`/`has_many` relationship with a full class name and foreign key - no difference.

I've tried varying versions of Rails 3.0.x from 3.0.1 to 3.0.20.  No effect.  Same issue.

I've tried all combos of plural and singular for `has_many` and `belongs_to` symbols.

Worst of all, I have a couple other relationships on different objects that seem to be happily setup.  They do not involve the `User` model which makes me fear that it is the `restful_authentication` bit.

I can't, for the life of me, figure out what's what.  If anyone has any ideas or has seen this before, I'd love some help.

I'm trying to get to Rails 3.0.20 with the intention of rolling forward to 3.1 and then 3.2 from there.  And really want to get a semi-stable version on 3.0.20 before I push further ahead.

Thanks, in advance, for any tips/tricks
Mr Rogers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the root of the issue.

For the old version (Rails 2.3.18), I was using `has_many_polymorphs`.  This plugin is no longer valid for Rails3.  I upgraded to a "Rails 3 compatible version" here https://github.com/jystewart/has_many_polymorphs which is compatible for Rails 3.2 but not 3.0.  The code in this gem patches `ActiveRecord::Reflection::ClassMethods`.  The patch does not fly with the way Rails 3.0.x builds associations.

I guess it's time to move to `ActiveRecord's` native :polymorphic support.